# Comparing datetime time in a while loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to compare two datetime times in a while loop in python and when they are equal I want to break out of the loop

I have created a while loop and in it I have an if statement that compares the two datetime times together. The problem is that the if statement doesn't execute

```py
d=datetime.datetime.strptime('01:26:00','%H:%M:%S')
dnow=datetime.datetime.now()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    if(dnow.time() != d.time()):
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
    else:
        print('Hello World')
        break
```

I am expecting when dnow.time() equals d.time() then the else statement gets executed. Print out of the program
2019-07-30 01:25:54.422644
2019-07-30 01:25:55.423967
2019-07-30 01:25:56.425256
2019-07-30 01:25:57.426535
2019-07-30 01:25:58.427819
2019-07-30 01:25:59.429103
2019-07-30 01:26:00.429910
2019-07-30 01:26:01.431201
2019-07-30 01:26:02.432484
2019-07-30 01:26:03.434393
2019-07-30 01:26:04.434830

Comment: time goes so fast - it is hard to get equal time - better check `>=` or `<=` instead of `==` or `!=`

Comment: tried <= but it didn't work

Comment: You're comparing against the same value on every iteration of the loop; you probably want to get rid of `dnow` and just check `if (datetime.datetime.now() >= d)`

Comment: then maybe you need `>=`. And display `d` and `dnow` to see what you have. maybe you have different dates - ie. `01.01.1970` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st problem:

Since you're waiting one second on each loop, I assume you want the comparison to be accurate to one second. Comparing the raw output of time() won't work, as the microsecond component will almost never match.

This loop breaks if the hour, minute, and second match, but ignores microseconds.

2nd problem:

In your code, you're only defining dnow once, so dnow.time() never changes. You need to define dnow within the loop.

Try this:

```
d=datetime.datetime.strptime('01:59:00','%H:%M:%S').time()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    if(now.hour != d.hour or now.minute != d.minute or now.second != d.second):
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
    else:
        print('Hello World')
        break
```